# I need a regular expression to my htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, match, regular-language

I'm very new to regular expression and I need to do a redirecting on my `.htacess` for some urls

Some examples are:

```
/lentes-de-contato/9/lentes-de-contato-biofinity-coopervision
/lentes-de-contato/9/lentes-de-contato-biofinity-teste
/lentes-de-contato/9/lentes-de-contato-biofinity
/lentes-de-contato/9/biofinity
```

The regex needs to match the word `biofinity` but don't match the word `coopervision`. I tried several ways to build an expression that looks like this: `"biofinity" AND !"coopervision"` but nothing seems to work. Till now I just have:

```
/lentes-de-contato/([0-9]+)/(.*biofinity.*)
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, so. Rewrterule will be achieved with your condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} biofinity
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !coopervision
RewriteRule
```

Comment: Nice, I just removed the first `RewriteCond` and added and /(\d+)/.*biofinity.* on my RewriteRule and it's working perfectly. Thank you for your help o/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `RewriteRule` itself using negative lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^lentes-de-contato/(\d+)/(?!.*?coopervision).*?-biofinity ... [L,NC]
```

Comment: I did't try it but seems also to work, thank you for you help.